# using "this" in a fragment gives me an error

Tags: android

```
public class Home extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        notes.add("Example note");
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,notes);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home,container,false);
    }
```

when i use this it gives me an error, tried using getactivity or getcontext and both crash the app when i do it

where did i go wrong
any suggestions are welcomed and thanks in advance <3

Comment: ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView); is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must get corresponding fragment view by below 2 lines

```
View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, container, false);
ListView lv = myView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Comment: How do you get the application context with that?

Comment: @FunnyO why do you need? if you need context , use `getActivity()`, `getContext()`,`this` and so on

Answer (score 1):

1. **getActivity()** may be null while your fragment is in process of preparation.

Just inflate your fragment layout in onCreateView and place ListView logic to **onViewCreated()** or **onActivityCreated**

2. Get listview from fragment by inflate, not from parent activity

Comment: i fixed it with it being in the onCreateView  , is it better if i make an onViewCreated() or activityCreated() and write my code there?

Comment: Yes, it is a safer place to ensure that your activity has been initiated. You can read more detail in developer docs : [onActivityCreated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)).

> Called when the fragment's activity has been created and this fragment's view hierarchy instantiated

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter needs a context as the first parameter, so either use `this.getContext()` or `this.getActivity()` instead of passing `this`, which is a fragment.

Furthermore, you should move the code into `onViewCreated` method, as the view must be inflated before you access its elements.

And you have to use `view.findViewById()` instead of `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Fragments do not inherit the context from an Activity. Try this:

```
 ListView listView = ((ListView) getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Same works for getContext.

```
 Context context = ((ListView) getActivity)).getApplicationContext();
```